# Change menu action item position - to the left side

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I've a menu.xml file, where I've:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="..">

    <item android:id="@+id/test_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="@string/.."
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

Any item I add here is being shown on the right side.
There's also default "back" button which I can easily hide/disable by `mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`. The position of "back" button is precisely what I want, just "custom" button. This should be only possible when entering specific Fragment, let's say `Fragment A`.

`Activity` is extending `AppCompatActivity`.

How can I do this? What is the best way (cleanest) of doing this? An example would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you have to create your own custom view for action bar and set it this way

```
mActionBar.setCustomView(customView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```